# Apple's Profile Manager (MDM) is suddenly unable to updates settings on enrolled iPads

Tags: ipad, macos, server.app, mobile-device-management

So I just noticed that all new iPads (and old ones that we removed from groups and added to other groups) is no longer able to push settings to the iPads.

The iPads are all on very different networks, and installing apps on them all seem to work.

I'm guessing this is a bug that was introduced in the last Server update. Running 10.9.2 and Server 3.1.1

Anyone else experiencing this or know what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix this here, but the reason it's failing is really strange.

I removed the Security & Privacy payload from the settings, which mostly consists of OS X settings, but also has "Allow sending diagnostics and usage data to Apple" setting for both OSX and iOS. I had a sneaking suspicion that this was somehow messing up since it mostly consisted of OS X settings, and turns out I was right.

Now WHY this would mess it up is baffling to me, I'll file a radar with Apple here as it's clearly not intended to fail as this payload belong to the OS X & iOS section. (And either way you can have both iOS devices and Macs in the same group, so OS X specific settings shouldn't cause problems for the iOS devices).